# MVC3 EditorFor not populated in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome, razor

I'm having trouble populating a textbox in a Create view. Pertinent code is as follows.

Model:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    private string _username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    public string UserName 
    {
        get
        { return _username; }
         set
        { _username = value;}
    }
```

}

View:

```
@model model.Client
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new Client());
}
```

This works perfectly in IE and Firefox; the `<input>` textbox is rendered with the value set to the current user's login name. In Chrome, however, the value is an empty string.

Can anyone explain this behavior and provide a workaround?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Does the HTML render the same in Chrome and Firefox if you inspect the element?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Do some initial debugging to watch your properties and all...

Comment: Erm, `HttpContext.Current`. In an ASP.NET MVC application? Why?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I'm interested to know; what's the correct call that he should be making in relation to HttpContext.Current as I must confess I do this because I thought it was correct when using FormsAuthentication - can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to use Html.TextBoxFor instead of EditorFor?